# C# SaveFileDialog CSV (MS-DOS)

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, savefiledialog

I'm using C# WPF and trying to save a file with a CSV (MS-DOS) type, every time it saves it as a normal CSV file.

How I can force it to be (MS-DOS) type?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "MS-DOS" type? How does it differ from a "normal" CSV file?

Comment: The encoding of the file is different, comma delimited CSV file has some problems so I need to have it as MS-DOS.

Comment: There is no official definition of an "MS-DOS" encoding, you really need to clarify what you mean: is it [Code Page 437?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) Where are you having problems with the encoding, and what kind of problems?

Comment: I actually have no idea, I have problem when I try to load a comma delimited CSV file, if I save the file(with execl) as MS-DOS I load the file ok.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://excel.tips.net/T009507_Comma-Delimited_and_MS-DOS_CSV_Variations.html) the difference is...

> If you export as Windows CSV, those fields are encoded using the Windows-1252 code page. DOS encoding usually uses code page 437, which maps characters used in old pre-Windows PCs.

So, you need to specify an encoding when you create your StreamWriter.  Maybe something along the lines of (untested)...

```
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open("filename", FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding(437)))
        {
            sw.WriteLine("my text...");
        }
```